# psql fe_sendauth no password supplied

Tags: postgresql

I am new to this type of database and I try to connect to it through the command line specifying psql, and then entering the password as blank. I get the above error (in the title of this question).

I dont know what the default password.

pg_hba file:

```
        IPv4 local connections:
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
    # IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
    # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
    # replication privilege.
    host    replication     DIMA        127.0.0.1/32            trust
    host    replication     DIMA        ::1/128                 trust
```

postgresql.config

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
```

I restart the server this way:

```
C:\metasploit\postgresql\bin\pg_ctl -D "C:\metasploit\postgresql\myData" -l logfile start
```

All I want is to enter the database and change my password. And preferably to enter the PgAdmin-III (in GUI form)

Answer (score 2):

If you were using `trust` authentication (which you should only use for development, if then) you would not be prompted for a password by `psql`.

I'd say you didn't properly restart the server. Maybe use `restart` instead of `start`?

Comment: I get this error too. It has nothing to do with restarting the database. PG prompts for a password with `psql --username=postgres --host=localhost` but not with `psql --username=postgres`, even though the two should be logically equivalent.

Comment: @Cerin The two are not equivalent on platforms that support unix sockets. The latter uses TCP/IP to whatever IP address `localhost` resolves as. The former is actually like saying `psql --username=postgres --host=/var/run/pgsql` (or wherever your `unix_socket_directory` is). I don't like that user interface much, but it ca't really be changed now. On Windows they'd be equivalent because it doesn't support unix sockets.

Answer (score 0):

As Craig said, you probably didn't restart the server and you should use restart instead of start.  (reload may work as well but not as sure on Windows)

But that is not your problem.  The key problem is almost certainly that you are not connecting to localhost and you have lines in your `pg_hba.conf` that are requiring passwords from other hosts.

Note if you connect to an external IP address, you will hit a different or more general rule.

This error means, basically, that the `pg_hba.conf` file is set to password authentication but no password was supplied.  If you cannot find the problem quickly, what IP address the connection is from should be in the postgresql log file.

As for using trust, you should certainly change it back after changing your password.  Ordinarily I would agree with Craig that one should not use trust authentication outside of development, but it is a legitimate approach to password resets of important users, and on Windows, this has to be done in ways supported well on the platform.

As a final note the question is how you are logging in.  If you are going to set this, you should probably use `psql -h 127.0.0.1 [dbname]` to ensure Windows doesn't do something weird like try to connect using the machine name (and hence external IP).